# Error CS1519 c# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't have a lot of experience using C#, and I am doing a game for school, and I have do give an animation to the character (Idle and walk), I'm using MixAmo to get the animations. But the code that the teacher gave me doesn't work... the error CS1519 keeps occurring and i can't fix it, please help me.

Here it is the code:

```
public class Controle : MonoBehaviour {

private Animator controller;
private float speed;
private Rigidbody rb;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<Animator>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    speed = 5 * Time.deltaTime;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        controller.Play("walking_inPlace");
    transform.Translate(0, 0, speed);

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        controller.Play("walking_inPlace");
    transform.Translate(0, 0, -speed);

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        controller.Play("walking_inPlace");
    transform.Translate(speed, 0, 0);

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        controller.Play("walking_inPlace");
    transform.Translate(-speed, 0, 0);
}
else 
{
 controller.Play("breathing_idle");
}
}
```

Comment: How exactly the error looks like, and in which line?

Comment: You may also have other issues: your if statements maybe missing block curly braces after them, as it seems that you want 2 lines to execute after each if statement, not one, i.e., both ```controller.Play``` and ```transform.Translate```, not just ```controller.Play```.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Update method:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update() {
    .......
}
else 
{
 controller.Play("breathing_idle");
}
```

The else is not only outside the method, but also does not correspond to any close if statement.
You more than likely wanted to do this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        controller.Play("walking_inPlace");
        transform.Translate(0, 0, speed);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        controller.Play("walking_inPlace");
        transform.Translate(0, 0, -speed);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        controller.Play("walking_inPlace");
        transform.Translate(speed, 0, 0);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        controller.Play("walking_inPlace");
        transform.Translate(-speed, 0, 0);
    }
    else 
    {
         controller.Play("breathing_idle");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have else instruction in wrong place, try this code:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
    controller.Play("walking_inPlace");
transform.Translate(0, 0, speed);
        }

        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
    controller.Play("walking_inPlace");
transform.Translate(0, 0, -speed);
        }

        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
    controller.Play("walking_inPlace");
transform.Translate(speed, 0, 0);
        }

        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
    controller.Play("walking_inPlace");
transform.Translate(-speed, 0, 0);
        }

else
{
    controller.Play("breathing_idle");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile. Don't post answers blindly

Comment: Correct your code to have `{` and `}` after each if statement because multiple things are being done on each one.

Answer (score 0):

**[Compiler Error CS1519](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1519)**

Invalid token 'token' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
This error is generated whenever a token is encountered in a location where it does not belong. A **token is a keyword**; an identifier (the name of a class, struct, method, and so on); a string, character, or numeric literal value such as 108, "Hello", or 'A'; or an operator or punctuator such as == or ;.

Any class, struct, or interface member declaration that contains invalid modifiers before the type will generate this error. To fix the error, remove the invalid modifiers.

In your **Particular case** (code snippet_ I will refer to **Camilo** and **pablocity** answers, you have placed your else statement outside of the update which is incorrect. Additionally, I think that you don't have command on C# so please have a look some tut to learn it first, then try coding in unity.